# XML Carriage return encoding

Tags: xml, encoding, whitespace

I was looking to represent a carriage return within an xml node.
I have tried a whitespace preserve, hex entity with no luck-  and a \n. viewing via a browser.

Example

```
<Quote>
Alas, poor Yorick!
I knew him
</Quote>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 85):

To insert a CR into XML, you need to use its character entity `&#13;`.

This is because compliant XML parsers must, before parsing, translate CRLF and any CR not followed by a LF to a single LF. This behavior is defined in the [End-of-Line handling](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends) section of the XML 1.0 specification.

Comment: Minor point - CR is &#13; and not &#10; which is LF - refer to this ascii table for details ... http://www.asciitable.com/  ...

Comment: Yes, &#10; is LF, &#13; is CR. Windows world usually has CRLF sequences (that is &#13;&#10;), Linux has just LF (&#10;).

Comment: I was not able to get this to work in decimal, but it was fine in hex &#A;

Comment: OMG, thank you sooooo much! My tests were failing because of this... :D

Comment: @MikeF Isn’t that an invalid character entity [because it isn’t decimal](https://gist.github.com/binki/d2d8da8cbfe4c5b50054ca371f2505c4)? Are you sure you’re feeding that to an XML parser?

Comment: @binki The SAX parser I was using only accepted the hex value.  Did not dig into the why.

Comment: Usually speaking, hexadecimal entities require an `x` after the `#`, as in `&#xa;` for ASCII character code 10.  Without the `x`, OxygenXML using the Saxon parser gives me the FATAL error message: _"A decimal representation must immediately follow the "&#" in a character reference."_

Answer (score 15):

`xml:space="preserve"` has to work for all compliant XML parsers.

However, note that in HTML the line break is just whitespace and NOT a line break (this is represented with the `<br />` (X)HTML tag, maybe this is the problem which you are facing.

You can also add `&#10;` and/or `&#13;` to insert CR/LF characters.

Comment: For the record the sequence on PCs at least is normally CR &#13; followed by LF &#10; but these days, a single LF is normally sufficient.

Comment: Also note that, even with `xml:space="prserve"`, the XML parser is still [required to replace `13 10` (and other sequences) with `10` before parsing](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-line-ends). You can enter a CR which is meant to survive parsing by [using a character entity reference such as `&#xD`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-common-syn).

Comment: @binki why are you OK with xD == 13 but not xA == 10?

Comment: @MikeF There’s never a need to encode `10`/`0xa` as a character entity. XML may be copied/pasted to different systems as text. If you do this, on some systems, a newline will be CRLF and on others LF or on others yet another character. Thus, XML spec says the processor shall normalize different sorts of newlines to `10`/`0xa` to ensure that XML transferred as text *always is parsed to the same exact value*. So, you only need to entitize non-`10` characters including CR (U+13), CR,NEL (U+13 U+85), and others listed at the W3C link. If I misunderstood your question please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

A browser isn't going to show you white space reliably. I recommend the Linux 'od' command to see what's really in there. Comforming XML parsers will respect all of the methods you listed.