# Escape a Carrage Return in XML

Tags: xml

I have a tag that looks like this:

```
<SomeTag V="Some Text Here"/>
```

If I wanted to add a carriage return between "Text" and "Here", how would I do that?

(**Note:** that the system that will receive this XML does not parse HTML in any way.)

Comment: do you want a carriage return, or a carriage return + line feed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML Carriage return encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265966/xml-carriage-return-encoding)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried checking this question: [XML Carriage return encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265966/xml-carriage-return-encoding) ?

It looks like using:

```
&#10;
```

seems to work for some users.

```
&#13;
```

might also work if that doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could use its character entity:

```
&#10;
```

Comment: I believe carriage return is `&#13` not `&#10`. `&#10` is Line Feed. Check the ascii table [link](http://www.asciitable.com/).