# How to get Axis2/Axiom to escape Carriage Returns?

Tags: xml, escaping, apache-axis

When creating a SOAP message using Axis2/Axiom I need to preserve the carriage returns in the body element. If I escape the CR to `&#xD;` (which is what is supposed to be done) Axis2/Axiom escapes the "&" to `&amp;`. If I do nothing Axis2/Axiom converts the CR to LF.

How do I get Axis2/Axiom to correctly escape the CR?

If that is not possible, how do I get Axis2/Axiom to ignore an already escaped sequence or perhaps even more simply, to leave a specific "&" alone?

I would prefer to be able to get Axis2/Axiom to escape the CR correctly to `&#xD;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preserving carriage returns (by replacing them with character references) should actually be the default in Axiom:

http://ws.apache.org/axiom/userguide/ch04.html#factory.properties

Maybe you are not using Woodstox as StAX implementation or there was a change between version 3 (which was the version used by Axiom at the time the documentation was written) and 4 of Woodstox (which is the version used by current Axiom releases).

Comment: yes, that appears to be correct. The XMLOutputFactory is javax and not woodstox. The javax default is apparently different. I will have to figure out how to move to woodstox and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Attempted to configure using `XMLOutputFactory xmlOutputFactory = StAXUtils.getXMLOutputFactory();
            xmlOutputFactory.setProperty(WstxOutputProperties.P_OUTPUT_ESCAPE_CR, true);` but I find that the object is immutable.

Comment: It appears all I had to do was add the woodstox jars to my classpath and the proper escaping appeared. No other code changes were necessary.

Comment: I removed the woodstox jars from the classpath and the CRs were once again changed to LFs. Interesting. Would have never guessed!

Answer (score 0):

The strings which you supply to Axis2 shouldn't already be escaped. Axis2 (or the XML layer) handles that for you. XML is supposed to canonicalize end-of-line characters in textual data; see [XML Carriage return encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265966/xml-carriage-return-encoding).

The real problem may be that you're using a datatype intended for textual data, when you really want to pass binary data through it. Can you redefine the relevant element of the WSDL as a base64binary or another binary-preserving type?

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately I cannot encode as base64. (I should add that this is a client.) The text data inside the body element must adhere to a format specified by a standard (its all printable ASCII except for the CR) and the service is not anticipating base64. The question really comes down to why isn't Axis2/Axiom escaping the CR to `&#xD;`. There must be a way to specify that but I do not know what it is. I am surprised its not done by default.