# Spring batch output force CR-LF as line seperator

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to force my spring batch to write file always with CR-LF[EDIT] as line seperator irrespective of the underlying system.

I was trying to use setLineSeperator of FlatFileItemWriter

```
<bean id="myFileWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
        <property name="lineSeparator">
        <value>\r\n</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

But it always generates file with "\r\n" as string. I am not sure how to unescape this. I looked at the source code of FlatFileItemWriter, there it is just appending the line seperator. Also they are using System.getProperty("line.seperator") for getting default value.

I am sure I am missing something pretty simple.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it does work with

```
<property name="lineSeparator" value="&#13;&#10;" />
```

To insert a CR into XML, you need to use its character entity `&#13;`, for CRLF you need `&#13;&#10;`

got it from this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2266166/62201)

for even more background and proper writing (it's not CL-RF) see [newline - Difference between \n and \r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java config, the following might be what you're looking for:

```
myFileWriter.setLineSeparator("\r\n");
```

When using the `"&#13;&#10;"` solution to write a .txt file, the result was a one line file with the `"&#13;&#10;"` showing up as straight text in the file.