# Why does xml.etree.ElementTree method findtext() convert \r\n to \n?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I have an XML file I use for testing and I test raw string against raw string. My test file contains the following data:

```
<output>
  first line\r\n
  second line\r\n
</output>
```

My to-be-tested function returns:

```
first line\r\n
second line\r\n
```

However, when I use `xml.etree.ElementTree` method `findtext('output')` (which should return text within `<output></output>` tags) the returned text has line separators replaced:

```
first line\n
second line\n
```

I have to replace them back, which is annoying. This behaviour is unexpected. Has anybody run into this issue and how do you handle it?

Comment: All XML compliant parsers [*must* convert CRLF line endings to LF](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2266166/190597). So you shouldn't need to write `\r\n`.

Comment: Please, add this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All XML compliant parsers [*must* convert CRLF line endings to LF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2266166/190597). So you shouldn't need to write `\r\n`.