# ElementTree changing newlines in text? How can I turn this off?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, elementtree

I am running into an issue with ElemenetTree messing with the text inside of xml when it parses a file or a string. We get xml where the line endings might be windows `\r\n` or unix `\n`. We are processing the text and pull offsets out of it. Since ET is messing with the actual text this means it becomes impossible to map our offsets back to the original text.

Running this minimal example shows the issue.

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> xml = '<element>this is text\r\nwith windows newlines</element>'
>>> e = ET.fromstring(xml)
>>> xml
'<element>this is text\r\nwith windows newlines</element>'
>>> e.text
'this is text\nwith windows newlines'
>>> print(xml)
<element>this is text
with windows newlines</element>
>>> print(e.text)
this is text
with windows newlines
```

The parsed text has the newlines converted from `\r\n` to `\n`

Initially I thought "thats not too bad, just replace all `\n` with `\r\n` again if the input string contains `\r` but looking at our data, we can get combos like `\r\r\n`, `\r\n\n`, etc. which create even stranger results from ET:

```
>>> xml = '<element>multiple returns\r\r\nget lost</element>'
>>> e = ET.fromstring(xml)
>>> e.text
'multiple returns\n\nget lost'
>>> xml = '<element>multiple returns\r\n\nget lost</element>'
>>> e = ET.fromstring(xml)
>>> e.text
'multiple returns\n\nget lost'
>>> xml = '<element>lone\rreturns? what??</element>'
>>> e = ET.fromstring(xml)
>>> e.text
'lone\nreturns? what??'
```

I have tested this in 2.7.15, python 3.7.3 and pypy 2.5.0 (python 2.7.8) (what I have currently on my machine) and all 3 exhibit the same behavior. I could not find anybody else running into this issue but the behavior does not feel right. Running the same tests in Java and C# with their built in libraries does not show this type of behavior.

Comment: Hi interesting, perhaps use xml entities instead of whitespace like: `xml = '<element>this is text&#13;&#10;with'`... Possibly due to how whitespace is handled in xml https://bugs.python.org/issue7139

Comment: @IronMan Interesting. I have never actually read the xml spec. We did go with just escaping the newlines with entities and that has worked. If you want to write your comment as an answer I would gladly give you the green check!

Comment: I'm trying to make a program that use XML and I also see that python ElementTree.fromstring changes /r/n to /n, THis answer might explain why: it's a standard . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265966/xml-carriage-return-encoding/2266166#2266166

Answer (score 0):

Want the data to stay the same? You can replace the original XML file with the data generated by ET. You can also try the following methods.

```
>>> from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
>>> xml = '<element>multiple returns\r\nget lost</element>'
>>> doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
>>> doc.element.html
'multiple returns\r\nget lost'
>>> doc.html
'<element>multiple returns\r\nget lost</element>'
```